# Is it possible to know if an iframe will allow content to be fullscreen?

Tags: html, iframe, fullscreen

I am creating an application that is expected to be embedded by other people in an iframe (much like a YouTube video). I have a fullscreen button that will call some variant of requestFullScreen if it's available, and this works fine so long as the iframe is embedded with

```
allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"
```

However, I don't know a way to tell whether the person who embedded the iframe has used these properties or not. If they haven't, clicking on the fullscreen button will do nothing.

I'd like to know ahead of time whether I'm going to be able to go fullscreen or not, so I don't show the button if I can't. Is there a way to do this?